# SharePoint Online List - days between two date columns

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, modern-experience, calculated-column-formula, date-time

I've got a very simple formula to calculate the number of days between two dates which works, with one exception.

Formula:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Completed Date]),"TBC",[Completed Date]-[Created Date])
```

When the 'Completed Date' value is empty I don't get 'TBC', instead SharePoint displays: `#VALUE!`

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my test, there is nothing wrong with the formula you provided.

[image]

**You can use the following formula instead:**

```
=IF([Completed Date]="","TBC",DATEDIF([Created Date],[Completed Date],"d"))
```

[image]

[image]

------------------------------------- **OR** ----------------------------------------

```
=IF([Completed Date]="","TBC",DATEDIF([Created Date],[Completed Date],"d"))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much, not sure why my formula works for you and not me, but your alternate suggestion worked for me, so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Syntax in your formula seems correct & it also works at my end.

**Example**:

[image]

---

Try below combinations & see which one works for you:

```
=IF([Completed Date] = "", "TBC", [Completed Date]-[Created Date])
```

OR

```
=IF(LEN([Completed Date])=0, "TBC", [Completed Date]-[Created Date])
```

Above two formula returns same results as shown in above image.

**Documentation**:

1. [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v=office.14))
2. [Examples of common formulas in lists](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/examples-of-common-formulas-in-lists-d81f5f21-2b4e-45ce-b170-bf7ebf6988b3)